# Loading an online image in a word document

Tags: c#, office-interop, openxml-sdk

Im developing a wpf app that simply inserts an image to a word document. Each time the word document is open i want the picture to call the image from a server, for example (server.com/Images/image_to_be_insert.png)
My code is as follow:

```
 Application application = new Application();
 Document doc = application.Documents.Open(file);

 var img = doc.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("server.com/Images/img.png");
 img.Height = 20;
 img.Width = 20;

 document.Save();
 document.Close();
```

Basically what my code does is, download the image then add it to the document. What i want to do is that i want the image to be loaded from the server whenever the word document is opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the Office Interop libraries, you could achieve this using the new OpenXML SDK which does not require MS Office to be installed in order to work.

**Requirements**

Install the OpenXML NuGet from Visual Studio: [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/2.7.2)

Add the required namespaces:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
```

**The code**

```
using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(@"c:/temp/img.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    package.AddMainDocumentPart();

    var picture = new Picture();
    var shape = new Shape() { Style="width: 272px; height: 92px" };
    var imageData = new ImageData() { RelationshipId = "rId1" };
    shape.Append(imageData);
    picture.Append(shape);

    package.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(
        new Body(
            new Paragraph(
                new Run(picture))));

            package.MainDocumentPart.AddExternalRelationship("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image",
   new System.Uri("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", System.UriKind.Absolute), "rId1");

    package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}
```

This will create a new Word document that will load the Google logo from the provided URL when open it.

**References**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440953(v=office.12).aspx

[How can I add an external image to a word document using OpenXml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609367/how-can-i-add-an-external-image-to-a-word-document-using-openxml)

Comment: what if i want to add a picture to an existing document. i tried to change the WordprocessingDocument.Create to WordprocessingDocument.open(path,true) but it exited with (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackageException: 'Only one instance of the type is allowed for this parent.') exception

Comment: You should be able to open it as you did, you also need to read the document part instead of creating it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478255.aspx